# CSS: html and body set to height: 100%, but divs don't resize height

Tags: css

I have

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

When i put a div with

```
div { height: 20%; }
```

it doesn't resize, it's height depends on its content.
I wish i can obtain a 20%.

Can you help me?

Comment: So you want to have the div the same height as the content in it? Or 20%? I'm confused

Comment: If your div should take 20% of the viewport height, use `vh`, example `div{height: 20vh}`

Comment: @MatthiasSeifert i want the div to have a 20% height. 20% or whathev dimension i want to.

Comment: @PascalGoldbach i know about vh but i want to understand why my css doesn't work :)

Comment: Your code should work fine --> https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/htse7xwz/ -- can you create a snippet or demo to clarify what you mean?

Comment: @ovokuro thanks, strange but true it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically your code should work. Check the demo here:

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
div{width: 20%}
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<body> 
  <div class="test">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dicat oportere in duo, te sea movet nominati. Liber exerci partem ei sed, ius eu denique lucilius expetendis. Pro et consectetuer definitiones, vix id augue singulis quaerendum. Ut vis accusamus reformidans, nam te similique omittantur.

An tincidunt dissentiet per, case timeam vix ad, ad modus affert has. Eu fastidii temporibus accommodare sit, percipit vituperata ne duo. Iriure dissentias te vis, est labore possim meliore cu, doming timeam ne sit. Ei has dico modus definitiones, dolorum atomorum suscipiantur ad eam. Facer mollis prodesset ad vis, est pertinax necessitatibus te. Has id iusto argumentum, ut ullum omnium forensibus vel.

Oblique indoctum vis ut. Eam an elitr ignota. Dico maiorum eu sea. Mel illum eirmod nostrud ei, movet malorum nostrud vel ne. Volumus mediocritatem vis ex, ad nostrum appellantur sea, in paulo aliquando vel.

Ea mea dolor accusam intellegat, adhuc phaedrum ei vis. Nam ea atqui homero salutandi, eu laudem quaerendum per. Cu vim legere graeco, vis facer summo albucius ex, pro utinam vulputate in. Ei debitis offendit qui, debet viris copiosae ius ea.

Nam utinam voluptatibus ex, et perfecto repudiandae nec. Ea dolore ponderum partiendo sea, est an fugit ceteros, te vis suas voluptatibus. Falli iuvaret pro ex. Ius at volutpat posidonium contentiones.</p>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```